# Firebase push notifications iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications

Can I send peer to peer notifications using Firebase? Example: UserA sends friend request to UserB. UserB receives this notification even if app is in the background.

Can push notifications be sent from client side? Example: UserA sends friend request to UserB. When this event occurs I connect to APNS straight from client. Is this a viable solution?

Reading other posts has been a bit confusing since Firebase has rolled out more functionality recently so I think many answers might be outdated.

Comment: You would implement same logic for ios or android. Firebase allows you to use **Device Groups** (Group of devices owned by user). On the group creation you can add a value in a table where you have `UserID : DeviceGroupID` so when you send notification you just ask notification from client to **DeviceGroupID**

Comment: @Mederic Thanks I wasn't aware of this feature. Perhaps I misused peer-peer since this doesn't cover every scenario. If UserA is sending a friend request to UserB I have no way of knowing who UserB is ahead of time, so I couldn't possibly know who to add in group. Perhaps when friend request event occurs, I create group? This seems like a hack, and in this Firebase case I think "group" refers a set of different devices that belong to a single user.

Comment: You can use **Firebase Function** to send peer to peer push notification. I have done a similar thing using Functions. You need to write your own function to send notification.

Comment: @AnonProgrammer You didnt undestand what device group is: UserA owns a Tablet and a Phone both logged in your app both Devices are added in a device group. **1 User = 1 Device Group = Multiple Devices**. and then when a user creates a group or gets the FCM Token you add **Username : FCM Token** to a database then easily send a notification getting the FCM Token. However **Peter Tao** mentioned the use of function which might be eaiser for you to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question - I coincidently had to do this a couple months ago.

1. You'll want to send notifications from the backend (Firebase). Not client. If configured on the backend you can change the notifications at any time without releasing a new version of your app.
2. Have a look into [Firebase cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). You can setup a Cloud Function to "observe" certain nodes of your real-time database. So when someone sends a "friend request" it changes data, which triggers the Cloud Function. The Cloud function in turn will read the new data (first name, last name, etc.) and sent the push notification to the corresponding user.
3. Use this example as a guide. https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications

Good luck!

Comment: When ready to send a notification to device I call `sendToDevice` method which takes a `String` as an argument.  The resource you provided says its a `device notification token`. Firebase says its a "registration token that comes from the client FCM SDKs". What should be the input here?

Comment: In order for FCM to send a notification it must know what device to send it to. Thus, the client must send it's specific token to the server. Checkout their docs to retrieve a client token: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/